# .NET WebSockets forcibly closed despite keep-alive and activity on the connection

Tags: c#, .net, websocket

We have written a simple WebSocket client using System.Net.WebSockets. The KeepAliveInterval on the ClientWebSocket is set to 30 seconds.

The connection is opened successfully and traffic flows as expected in both directions, or if the connection is idle, the client sends Pong requests every 30 seconds to the server (visible in Wireshark).

But after 100 seconds the connection is abruptly terminated due to the TCP socket being closed at the client end (watching in Wireshark we see the client send a FIN). The server responds with a 1001 Going Away before closing the socket.

After a lot of digging we have tracked down the cause and found a rather heavy-handed workaround. Despite a lot of Google and Stack Overflow searching we have only seen a couple of other examples of people posting about the problem and nobody with an answer, so I'm posting this to save others the pain and in the hope that someone may be able to suggest a better workaround.

The source of the 100 second timeout is that the WebSocket uses a System.Net.ServicePoint, which has a MaxIdleTime property to allow idle sockets to be closed. On opening the WebSocket if there is an existing ServicePoint for the Uri it will use that, with whatever the MaxIdleTime property was set to on creation. If not, a new ServicePoint instance will be created, with MaxIdleTime set from the current value of the System.Net.ServicePointManager MaxServicePointIdleTime property (which defaults to 100,000 milliseconds).

The issue is that neither WebSocket traffic nor WebSocket keep-alives (Ping/Pong) appear to register as traffic as far as the ServicePoint idle timer is concerned. So exactly 100 seconds after opening the WebSocket it just gets torn down, despite traffic or keep-alives.

Our hunch is that this may be because the WebSocket starts life as an HTTP request which is then upgraded to a websocket. It appears that the idle timer is only looking for HTTP traffic. If that is indeed what is happening that seems like a major bug in the System.Net.WebSockets implementation.

The workaround we are using is to set the MaxIdleTime on the ServicePoint to int.MaxValue. This allows the WebSocket to stay open indefinitely. But the downside is that this value applies to any other connections for that ServicePoint. In our context (which is a Load test using Visual Studio Web and Load testing) we have other (HTTP) connections open for the same ServicePoint, and in fact there is already an active ServicePoint instance by the time that we open our WebSocket. This means that after we update the MaxIdleTime, all HTTP connections for the Load test will have no idle timeout. This doesn't feel quite comfortable, although in practice the web server should be closing idle connections anyway.

We also briefly explore whether we could create a new ServicePoint instance reserved just for our WebSocket connection, but couldn't see a clean way of doing that.

One other little twist which made this harder to track down is that although the System.Net.ServicePointManager MaxServicePointIdleTime property defaults to 100 seconds, Visual Studio is overriding this value and setting it to 120 seconds - which made it harder to search for.

Comment: By coincidence, I stumbled into this behavior just the other day. Does seem like a bug. Consider reporting it to CLR team. It should be possible to protect the websocket from being closed when ServicePoint times out by setting some internal fields with reflection, but I'm not entirely comfortable with either solution.

Comment: Thank you! I spent the last two days trying to figure out why my internal ClientWebsocket mysteriously kept disconnecting after roughly 100 seconds, until I stumbled upon this post. Seems to have resolved my issue.

Comment: System.Net.ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = int.MaxValue;

Answer (score 16):

I ran into this issue this week.  Your workaround got me pointed in the right direction, but I believe I've narrowed down the root cause.

If a "Content-Length: 0" header is included in the "101 Switching Protocols" response from a WebSocket server, WebSocketClient gets confused and schedules the connection for cleanup in 100 seconds.

Here's the offending code from the [.Net Reference Source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/90b323fe52bec428fe4bd5f007e9ead6b265d553/System/net/System/Net/HttpWebResponse.cs#L522):

```
//if the returned contentlength is zero, preemptively invoke calldone on the stream.
//this will wake up any pending reads.
if (m_ContentLength == 0 && m_ConnectStream is ConnectStream) {
    ((ConnectStream)m_ConnectStream).CallDone();
}
```

According to RFC 7230 Section 3.3.2, Content-Length is prohibited in 1xx (Informational) messages, but I've found it mistakenly included in some server implementations.

For additional details, including some sample code for diagnosing ServicePoint issues, see this thread: https://github.com/ably/ably-dotnet/issues/107

Comment: This behavior is still present in the most recent .NET 4.7.1 on the client side, and IIS Express 10.0.14358 is sending `Content-Length: 0` in its `101` response.

Answer (score 6):

I set the KeepAliveInterval for the socket to 0 like this:

```
theSocket.Options.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.Zero;
```

That eliminated the problem of the websocket shutting down when the timeout was reached. But then again, it also probably turns off the send of ping messages altogether.

Answer (score 2):

I studied this issue these days, compared capture packages in Wireshark(webclient-client of python and WebSocketClient of .Net), and found what happened. In WebSocketClient, "Options.KeepAliveInterval" only send one packet to the server when no message received from server in these period. But some server only judge if there is active message from client.  So we have to manually send arbitrary packets (not necessarily ping packets,and WebSocketMessageType has no ping type) to the server at regular intervals,even if the server side continuously sends packets. That's the solution.