# .NET WebSocket closing for no apparent reason

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, websocket

I am testing how .NET WebSockets work when the client can't process data from the server side fast enough. For this purpose, I wrote an application that sends data continuously to a WebSocket, but includes an artificial delay in the receive loop. As expected, once the TCP window and other buffers fill, the SendAsync calls start to take long to return. But after a few minutes, one of these exceptions is thrown by SendAsync:

> System.Net.HttpListenerException: The device does not recognize the command
>   System.Net.HttpListenerException: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.

What's weird is, that this only happens with certain message sizes and certain timing. When the client is allowed to read all data unrestricted, the connection is stable. Also, when the client is blocked completely and does not read at all, the connection stays open.

Examining the data flow through Wireshark revealed that it is the server that is resetting the TCP connection while the client's TCP window is exhausted.

I tried to follow this answer ([.NET WebSockets forcibly closed despite keep-alive and activity on the connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40502921/net-websockets-forcibly-closed-despite-keep-alive-and-activity-on-the-connectio)) without success. Tweaking the WebSocket keep alive interval has no effect. Also, I know that the final application needs to be able to handle unexpected disconnections gracefully, but I do not want them to occur if they can be avoided.

Did anybody encounter this? Is there some timeout tweaking that I can do? Running this should produce the error between a minute and half to three minutes:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = Int32.MaxValue; // has no effect

        HttpListener httpListener = new HttpListener();
        httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://*/ws/");
        Listen(httpListener);

        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Receive("ws://localhost/ws/");

        Console.WriteLine("running...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static async void Listen(HttpListener listener)
    {
        listener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            HttpListenerContext ctx = await listener.GetContextAsync();

            if (!ctx.Request.IsWebSocketRequest)
            {
                ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented;
                ctx.Response.Close();
                return;
            }

            Send(ctx);
        }
    }

    private static async void Send(HttpListenerContext ctx)
    {
        TimeSpan keepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5); // tweaking has no effect
        HttpListenerWebSocketContext wsCtx = await ctx.AcceptWebSocketAsync(null, keepAliveInterval);
        WebSocket webSocket = wsCtx.WebSocket;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
        while (true)
        {
            await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), WebSocketMessageType.Binary, true, CancellationToken.None);
        }
    }

    private static async void Receive(string serverAddress)
    {
        ClientWebSocket webSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
        webSocket.Options.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5); // tweaking has no effect

        await webSocket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(serverAddress), CancellationToken.None);

        byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[10000];
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(10); // simulate a slow client

            var message = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(receiveBuffer), CancellationToken.None);
            if (message.CloseStatus.HasValue)
                break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I was hitting an HTTP.SYS low speed connection attack countermeasure, as roughly described in KB 3137046 (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3137046/http-sys-forcibly-disconnects-http-bindings-for-wcf-self-hosted-servic):

> By default, Http.sys considers any speed rate of less than 150 bytes per second as a potential low speed connection attack, and it drops the TCP connection to release the resource.

When HTTP.SYS does that, there is a trace entry in the log at %windir%\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR

Switching it off was simple from code:

```
httpListener.TimeoutManager.MinSendBytesPerSecond = UInt32.MaxValue;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a .NET developer but as far as I have seen these kind of problems in websocket topic and in my own opinion, these can be the reasons:

1. Very short timeout setting on websocket on both sides.
2. Client/Server side runtime exceptions (beside of logging, must check `onError` and `onClose` methods to see why)
3. Internet or connection failures. Websocket sometimes goes into IDLE mode too. You have to implement a heartbeat system on websockets to keep them alive. Use `ping` and `pong` packets.
4. check maximum binary or text message size on server side. Also set some buffers to avoid failure when message is too big.

As you said your error usually happens within a certain time, 1 and 2 must help you. Again sorry if I cant provide you codes, but I have had same problems in java and I found out these are the settings that must be set in order to work with websockets. Search how to set these in your client and server implementations and you must be fine after that.