# Azure web app: Web sockets abort after 100 seconds

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, owin

I'm writing a web socket application which I intend on hosting on the cloud using an Azure web app.

The web socket is implemented using a fairly standard piece of Owin Middleware and is fully functional for the first 100 seconds. After this time the websocket seems to enter the aborted state like clockwork.

```
[CLIENT][06/04/2018 11:27:21] WS client connected
[CLIENT][06/04/2018 11:29:01] WS client disconnected
```

Trying this on an IIS Express instance gives the same issue, although the delay seems to be 90 seconds rather than 100 (this is also consistent).

Running the same websocket as part of an Owin self-host app yields stability for over 25 minutes - so this definitely seems to be a problem caused by the hosting server.

On the azure web app hosting I've enabled web sockets, and also tried to enable the "Always On" feature in hopes that this would prevent the issue by preventing the server from going into a standby state - but this has not helped.

Are there any azure settings that I'm not aware of that could be tweaked such that these web sockets can stay open for longer periods of time?

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that azure and IIS were both red herrings, the issue instead was an issue experienced with using the C# implementation of System.Net.Websockets.ClientWebSocket. The detail is brilliantly summarized at: [.NET WebSockets forcibly closed despite keep-alive and activity on the connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40502921/net-websockets-forcibly-closed-despite-keep-alive-and-activity-on-the-connectio)

To others experiencing this issue, an effective (but not ideal) work around is to run the following once before creating a client web socket:

`ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = int.MaxValue;`